# Trouble using a sprite for pagination with jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I'm using [this jQuery slideshow plugin](http://www.slidesjs.com/), and trying to customize the pagination buttons by putting numbers in the circles. I ended up making a sprite with 4 circles to do this.

It's currently working for the 1 button, but I'm unsure on how to make numbers 2-4 show up.  [Here is the JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJvKC/) with some of the code (and there is some CSS below).  I think I'm stuck logically at this point.  Any suggestions would be great. [image: What I currently have.]. [image: This is my sprite.]

```
.slidesjs-pagination li a {
  display: block;
  width: 102px;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 102px;
  background-image: url(img/buttons.png);
  background-position: 0 0;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
.slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {
  background-position: 0 -102px;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
  background-position: 0 -204px;
}



/* Don't worry much about this jQuery, I found it in the plugin, it seems to be 
   producing the number based on how many images there are.  Although this isn't what 
   I want to do anymore, since I know I have 4 images. */


if (this.options.pagination.active) {
            i = e("<ul>", {
                "class": "slidesjs-pagination"
            }).appendTo(n);
            e.each(new Array(this.data.total), function (t) {
                var n, r;
                n = e("<li>", {
                    "class": "slidesjs-pagination-item"
                }).appendTo(i);
                r = e("<a>", {
                    href: "#",
                    "data-slidesjs-item": t,
                    html: t + 1
                }).appendTo(n);
                return r.click(function (t) {
                    t.preventDefault();
                    a.stop(!0);
                    return a.goto(e(t.currentTarget).attr("data-slidesjs-item") * 1 + 1)
                })
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, you need to increase the background-position x property to move the sprite sideways. Using css3 :nth-child() selector gives you this:

```
.slidesjs-pagination-item:nth-child(2) a {
    background-position: -102px 0 !important;
}
.slidesjs-pagination-item:nth-child(3) a {
    background-position: -204px 0 !important;
}
.slidesjs-pagination-item:nth-child(4) a {
    background-position: -306px 0 !important;
}
```

You must also add rules for active state and hover

```
.slidesjs-pagination-item:nth-child(2) a.active,
.slidesjs-pagination-item:nth-child(2) a.:hover.active {
    background-position: -102px -102px !important;
}
.slidesjs-pagination-item:nth-child(2) a:hover {
    background-position: -102px -204px !important;
}
/* add rules for 3 and 4 */
```

Simpler css code would use background-position-x instead, but it is not standard css. Using this means you don't need to set active and hover states..

```
.slidesjs-pagination-item:nth-child(2) a {
    background-position-x: -102px !important;
}
/* add rules for 3 and 4 */
```

The :nth-child() selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier.

But if I were you, I'd change the css to this to get the same result:

```
.slidesjs-pagination li a {
  display: block;
  width: 102px;
  height: 102px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white
}

.slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
.slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
  background-color: #59F
}
```

border-radius: 50% makes a square block item round..